# Como usar ng-disabled con ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Es posible habilitar un checkbox generado por un ng-repeat, sé que debemos tener en cuenta el índice por el ng-repeat que estoy usando, como lo estoy haciendo activa o desactiva todos los checkbox al mismo tiempo.

```
 <input ng-model="data.acepta"
        class="flipswitch"
        name="acepta"
        style="width:50px"
        id="acepta"
        ng-disabled= "locked"
        type="checkbox"
        >
```

En el js dentro del controlador tengo esto, la variable idx tiene el index del ng-repeat:

```
    if(TIPITV[idx]=="Ok")
    { 

      $scope.locked = false;

    }
```

Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estás `$scope.locked` para todos los checkboxs. Por ello cuando habilitas o deshabilitas todos se marcan o no.

Si vas a usar el `ng-repeat` debes usar un `array`.

Ejemplo:

**En tu controlador declara una variable/modelo:**

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.items.push({id: 1, name: 'Nombre 1', check: true});
$scope.items.push({id: 2, name: 'Nombre 2', check: false});
$scope.items.push({id: 3, name: 'Nombre 3', check: true});
```

**Ahora en tu vista html.**

Usalo de la siguiente forma:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check" /> {{item.name}}
</div>

<!-- Con este código puedes ver como se modifica el atributo "check" de cada elemento por separado. -->
<pre>{{items|json}}</pre>
```

Espero te sirva de guía.

Answer (score 0):

Tú mismo diste en el clavo al indicar que cada `checkbox` debe tener un **id diferente** colega, sólo te falta implementar de forma un poco más eficiente el problema.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [
    { nombre: 'Gokú', raza: 'Saiyayin', casado: true },
    { nombre: 'Picolo', raza: 'Namek', casado: false },
    { nombre: 'Vegeta', raza: 'Saiyayin', casado: true }
  ]
  
  $scope.selection = function(item){
    if(item.checked)
      alert('Seleccionaste a ' + item.nombre);
  }
}])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Raza</th>
        <th>Comprometido</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-bind="row.nombre"></td>
        <td ng-bind="row.raza"></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-2x" ng-class="row.casado ? 'fa-check text-success' : 'fa-times text-danger'"></i></td>
        <td>
          <div>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="{{row.nombre}}" ng-model="data[$index].checked" ng-change="selection(row)">
              <span></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Acá solamente le asigne un valor diferente a cada **propiedad id** - *en este caso el nombre del item* -, y posteriormente guardo en el `ng-model` el estado del checkbox (*true/false*)

Nos comentas si te sirve =)

Comment: Buenas tardes

Gracias a todos por su ayuda, finalmente lo logre realizar así: En el select agregué un ng-change="function(data,$index)" y en el js cambio el estado del check con la función que defini usando elemento[index].click();

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dicen arriba es correcto, dentro de un *ng-repeat* `$scope.locked` debería ser un **array**, de otro modo sucede que todos cambian a la vez por que están controlados por la misma variable.

En tu ejemplo puntual seria:

```
<input ng-model="data.acepta"
       class="flipswitch"
       name="acepta"
       style="width:50px"
       id="acepta"
       ng-disabled="locked[$index]"
       type="checkbox"
       >
```

y en el codigo

```js
$scope.locked = [];

if (TIPITV[idx] === "Ok")
{ 
  $scope.locked[idx] = false;
}
```